# Changing control text on Web form masterpage with resources

Tags: c#, webforms, resources, master-pages

I currently have a Web Forms project that I am working on. All of my websites have the same master page and inherit from my custom class that inherits from the Page class, so I can do check the Session or Cookies etc. from the parent class.
What I want to do now is get the title Label from the Master Page to my class that inherits the Page class and depending on the site that I'm on, I want it to display a different title. Also the title needs to be in two languages, depending on the culture selected. I have three .resx files for the default, first and second language for each page. Is there a way to get the string from the correct .resx file depending on the culture? Or is my whole approach wrong and need to do something else? Please leave a comment if you know, here is my code. The following function gets called on the preInit event of my custom Page class.

```
 private void SetTitle()
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)this.Master.FindControl("asplblTitle");

           lbl.Text = ...



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a similar problem, this eventually helped me:

```
    private void SetTitle()
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)this.Master.FindControl("asplblTitle");


        string sPagePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        System.IO.FileInfo oFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPagePath);
        string sPageName = oFileInfo.Name;

        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("RWA_WebForms.App_GlobalResources." + sPageName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        lbl.Text = rm.GetString("Title", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);




    }
```

Tried everything I found on the internet, but giving this full path eventually did the trick. Also changing the build action of .resx files to Embedded Resource.